# Can I create django model, which will be not persisted in database?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

As asked in question:
Can I create django model(models.Model), which will be not persisted in database?

The reason is I want use it in my django admin to build custom form basing on forms.ModelForm

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can override the model's `save()` method to prevent saving to the database, and use `managed = False` to prevent Django from creating the appropriate tables:

```
class NonPersistantModel(models.Model):
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

Note that this will raise an error when a bulk operation tries to save instances of this model, as the `save` method wouldn't be used and the table wouldn't exist. In your use-case (if you only want to use the model to build a `ModelForm`) that shouldn't be a problem.

However, I would strongly recommend building your form as a subclass of `forms.Form`. Models are abstractions for your database tables, and plain forms are capable of anything a generated `ModelForm` can do, and more.

Comment: I was not able to judge if this suggestion is a best practice or just something that works. In an extreme case, if I were to use a model with credit card info which means it cannot be ever persisted to database hwo should write the code? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

It's easier to just use `forms.Form`:

```
class UserForm(forms.Form):
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

Comment: but, how to bind it easily in django admin?

Comment: There are quite a few guides on this, but it's not easy. You'll  basically have to create a view, add a url to the admin urls and extend an admin template.