# Django model prevent saving to database

Tags: django, django-models

It seems that I already asked this question and got an answer, but I can't find it.

How to make a Django model not stored in the DB? I want it to be a model (derived from `models.Model`) only in order to be able to retrieve it with `get_model()` method.

Comment: U might want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22690330/can-i-create-django-model-which-will-be-not-persisted-in-database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model fields here

    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

More on this in the [`managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#managed) setting.

Comment: I do not think this answer matches the question.